# why my result is 1436189223 ? Please help me explan this result

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[]myArray = new int[5];
    for(int index =0;index<myArray.length;index++) 
    myArray[3]=100*myArray[3]*myArray[3]+3;
    System.out.println("myArray[]="+myArray[3]);

}
```

please help me why myArray[] result is 1436189223

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: You do realize that you're actually just setting the same array value over and over again, right? You could replace this by using a single variable and hardcoding the for loop length and not bother with the array.

Comment: Also, did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over it step by step (**which is what you can do in the debugger as well!!**):

1. `int[]myArray = new int[5];`: This will be an array `{0,0,0,0,0}`. An array of size 5, with default `int`-value `0`.
2. `for(int index=0; index<myArray.length; index++)`: Loop in the range `[0, 5)`:
3. `myArray[3] = 100*myArray[3]*myArray[3]+3;`: Let's split this into substeps below:

   1. `myArray[3] = 100 * 0 * 0 + 3` results in `3`
   2. `myArray[3] = 100 * 3 * 3 + 3` results in `903`
   3. `myArray[3] = 100 * 903 * 903 + 3` results in `81540903`
   4. `myArray[3] = 100 * 81540903 * 81540903 + 3` results in `-749594073`
   5. `myArray[3] = 100 * -749594073 * -749594073 + 3` results in `1436189223`
4. `System.out.println("myArray[]="+myArray[3]);`: Print the value of `myArray[3]`, thus `1436189223`.

Some things to note. First of all, why use `myArray[3]` to begin with.. This would be a simpler alternative, since you don't use the array at all:

```
int result=0;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) 
   result = 100*result*result+3;
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

But the part where your question is probably mostly about is why `100 * 81540903 * 81540903 + 3` results in `-749594073`. This is because the maximum `int` size is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (`2,147,483,647`). After that it will wrap around. So `int i = 2147483647 + 1` will result in `-21474836481` (or more in general `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE`).
The same applies to other data types, like `byte`, `short`, `long`, etc. [Here you can see some of those ranges per data type.](https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html)

Since `long` is 64-bit instead of `int`'s 32-bit, it can be used to get the correct result here:

```
long result=0L;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) 
   result = 100*result*result+3;
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoIwEETvfsWEE9hIaowXkT/QixyNhwpIiqUl7UJiDN9eC7iHmezOy2wrRrFrq7f3pRLO4Sqk/m6AfngqWcKRoGCjkRW6EMUFWamb@wPCNi7BjALK6Aa2doOinF@y5fYyNpaaIHOeQZ6PQRhLsGRhVho59pxv1@Vv7LAWFB9HdZeagdI@/CSl4@i2ECdEbGWTGZ02k/c/)

Or using your original code:

```
long[]myArray = new long[5]; // <- This is a long-array now
for(int index =0;index<myArray.length;index++) 
   myArray[3]=100*myArray[3]*myArray[3]+3;
System.out.println("myArray[]="+myArray[3]);
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##TY5NDoIwEIX3nGLCCiQSDHGFXXgAVyxJFxUqVktL2oISw9lr@TE4m5l5732ZeZCe7B/V09qSE63hQpj4eABtd@WsBG2Ica2XrILGWUFuFBN1gYGoWocwRQG4nKRmOCtFBkAg6GvRjjibAzepAiYMMFHRN6Akm4fTSsScitrcFzGKQpgZV6tfpBgdkmS3rX9jlC4n8kEb2sSyM3HrXjRcBP4vhZEfbUQ4AaM3WvsF)

PS: If you have to go even beyond the size of `long`, you'll have to use `java.math.BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple actually, your loop runs 5 times. In each iteration it uses the previous values of `myArray[3]`, computes the new value and then the stores that value in the same index.

When :-

> index = 0 ; myArray[3] = 3
>
> index = 1 ; myArray[3] = 903
>
> index = 2 ; myArray[3] = 81540903
>
> index = 3 ; myArray[3] = -749594073
>
> index = 4 ; myArray[3] = 1436189223

Also, note that since you have not used brackets around the `for-loop`, it considers only the next immediate line to be a part of the loop.